# jQuery hide/show code not working in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, show-hide

So here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULHVe/1/) and here's the code. It works in everything I've tested apart from IE7. Any idea why? It's a very simplified version of what I currently have but hopefully you get the idea.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<p><span class="score">Please click here to toggle views</span></p>
<div id="score">Score Content</div>
<div id="escalation">Escalation Content</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#escalation").show();
        $("#score").hide();

        $(".score").click(function () {
            $("div#escalation").toggle("slow", function () { });
            $("div#score").toggle("slow", function () { });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Tell me about it. Unfortunately I work for local government. IE7 is on the front-line of cutting technology as far as they are concerned.

Comment: @JanuszJasinski Hi Could you please try: http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-show-hide-plugin/

Comment: even jsfiddle does not work with IE7

Comment: @ManojMevada that does seem to work in IE7 thanks

Comment: How could you see this is not working when jsFiddle itself does not work in IE7?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try below link?

http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-show-hide-plugin/